# Bowling score calculator MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Having a slight problem with my bowling score calculator. I'm just a little bit off here and I'm fairly sure it has to do with the last frame. I don't know though.
A little bit about the loaded variable.
bowling.xls contains data for 50 games of bowling, so games is a 50x21 matrix.
The 21 columns correspond with each ball thrown. 
Thank you guys for any help. If you do not know Matlab, you're welcome to respond in universal code.

EDIT: Here is my up to date code. As you can see the "current" variable is now being preset to show the game I am trying to calculate, so you guys can see it for debugging purposes. The output I am getting from this program is 158. It should be 194.

```
i = 1;
gamescore = 0;
current =  [10 0 6 0 9 1 10 0 10 0 8 2 8 2 8 0 10 0 10 10 10]
strikes = zeros(1,10);
spares = zeros(1,10);

% Check for strikes
for j=1:10
    if current(2*j-1) == 10
        strikes(j) = 1;
    end
end

% Check for spares
for j=1:10
    if (current(2*j-1) + current(2*j) == 10) && (current(2*j-1)~=10)
        spares(j) = 1;
    end
end

% Calculate score
for j=1:10
    if strikes(j) == 1
        gamescore = gamescore + 10 + current(2*j) + current(2*j+1);
    elseif spares(j) == 1
        gamescore = gamescore + 10 + current(2*j);
    else
        gamescore = gamescore + current(2*j-1) + current(2*j);
    end
end
fprintf('Game score: %d \n',gamescore)
```

Comment: Also, some debugging advice: make the data show you where the bugs are! Does a game of all strikes give you 300? That would show a bug in the strike math. Does a game of all 10s in the second ball give you 100? That would show a bug in the spare math. Does a game of all strikes except the first frame give you the expected results? This would indicate a bug in the math that calculates the score of an open frame

Comment: Also `strikespot` and `sparespot` confused me, as they are no different than `j` in their respective loops, but you may have your own reasons for wanting these

Comment: Could you post an example game with the score you get and the score you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it!! After a bunch of messing around, using a bunch of your guys' methods mixed with my own, I was finally able to scrounge up the code. Here it is! If you have any questions as to why I did something, I will happy to explain, as you guys were so kind to do the same to me.

```
i = 1;
gamescore = 0;
current = games(i,:);
strikes = zeros(1,12);
spares = zeros(1,10);

% Check for strikes
for j=1:9
    if current(2*j-1) == 10
        strikes(j) = 1;
    end
end
for j=1:3
    if current(18+j)==10
        strikes(9+j) = 1;
    end
end

% Check for spares
for j=1:10
    if (current(2*j-1) + current(2*j) == 10) && (current(2*j-1)~=10)
        spares(j) = 1;
    end
end

% Calculate score
for j=1:10
    if strikes(j) == 1
        if strikes(j+1)==1
            gamescore = gamescore + 20 + current(2*j+1);
        else
            gamescore = gamescore + 10 + current(2*j) + current(2*j+1);
        end
    elseif spares(j) == 1
        gamescore = gamescore + 10 + current(2*j+1);
    else
        gamescore = gamescore + current(2*j-1) + current(2*j);
    end
end
fprintf('Game score: %d \n',gamescore)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider this code:

```
else
    score(1,j) = current(1,j) + current(1,j+1);
```

If there is no strike or spare in the 5th frame, `j=5`, What will the score be? From the code it will be

```
= current(1,j) + current(1,j+1);
= 5th Ball + 6th Ball
= Score of frame 3
```

From this it should be clear that the code needs to change to

```
else
    score(1,j) = current(1,2*j-1) + current(1,2*j);
```

EDIT:
After testing, the code also fails if there are 2 consecutive strikes. It is simple to add a check for this, just change:

```
if strikes(1,j) == 1
    score(1,j) = 10 + current(1,2*j+1) + current(1,2*j+2);
```

To

```
if strikes(1,j) == 1
    if strikes(1,j+1) == 1
        score(1,j) = 10 + current(1,2*j+1) + current(1,min(2*j+3,20));
    else
        score(1,j) = 10 + current(1,2*j+1) + current(1,2*j+2);
    end
```

Comment: This part `min(2*j+3,20)` is to make sure the first two balls of the 10th frame are counted if there is a strike in the 9 and strike in the 1st ball of the 10th as well.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. At first I was on board, but it seems I am still not getting the score I should be. I updated my score calculation section to be what I have now. Any thoughts now?
I guess I'll try to have an integer variable 'gamescore' and add to it each iteration instead of adding them to a vector and summing it. Not sure that will make a difference though.

Comment: Are you trying to find the maximum score over all 51 games? This seems to be what your comments indicate, but not what your code is doing. To do this, you would need to add a for loop to iterate over games instead of just declaring `i=1`, set `gamescore(i) = sum(score)`, and return the max of `gamescore`

Comment: Well 50 games, yes. I have my for loop from i=1:50; I have it commented out though just for testing purposes.

Comment: This code is working for me and my games. Could you post what the error is now? What are the inputs and what are the outputs?

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't well-vectorized for matlab.

The only for-loop you should need should be the one to add in the dummy zero-rounds after each strike (so as to distinguish strikes from 0-10 spares.  I assume from the fact that it's 21 columns and not 22 that the data isn't already arranged into frames for you, but is rather zero-padded at the end.  If you can change the input format so that it's given in frames, then you can obtain a vector of all scores for all games simultaneously without having to loop over them).
Otherwise everything else can be vectorized, ex.

```
for idx = 1 : 2 : 19
 if game(idx) == 10
  game = [game(1 : idx), 0, game(idx : 21)]
 end
end
```

Because of the possibility of bowling a perfect 300 game, I don't believe there's any way to vectorize this.  You can't know for certain whether a 0-10 is a strike or a spare until you've handled all the previous frames

But now it's easy to obtain spare and strike indices and also scores

```
startscore = sum(game(1 : 20));

game = reshape(game,11,2);

spares = game(1 : 10, 1) + game(1 : 10, 2) == 10;

sparescore = sum(game(2 : 11, 1)(spares));

strikes = game(1 : 10, 1) == 10;

strikescore = sum(game(2 : 11, 2)(strikes));

score = startscore + sparescore + strikescore
```

Comment: Good idea! It should be really easy to vectorize over all games by replacing all instances of `current(1,` with `games(:,`. Also, make `strikes`, `spares`, and `score` have has many rows as `games`. It looks to me like the data are already in frames, as 21 = 9 frames of 2 balls + 3 balls in the 10th frame, and the code as written depends on the `jth` frame being in `current(1,2*j-1:2*j)`

Comment: In that case you can vectorize over all games simultaneously.  I'll post another answer

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to show how to solve it if the data is already arranged into frames.

In this case I'm assuming that the dummy zero after a strike is already present except on the very last frame.

```
function [scores] = getscores(games)
 [n, m] = size(games);
 assert(m == 21);
 games = [games, zeros(n, 1)];
 lastwasstrike = games(:, 19) == 10;
 games(lastwasstrike, 21 : 22) = games(lastwasstrike, 20 : 21);
 games(lastwasstrike, 20) = 0;
 startscores = sum(games(:, 1:20), 2);
 isspare = games(:, 1:2:19) + games(:, 2:2:20) == 10
 sparescores = sum((games(:, 3:2:21).*isspare), 2)

 isstrike = games(:, 1:2:19) == 10
 strikescores = sum((games(:, 4:2:22).*isstrike), 2)

 isdoublestrike = games(:, 1:2:17) == 10 & games(:, 3:2:19) == 10
 doublestrikescores = sum((games(:, 5:2:21).*isdoublestrike), 2)
 scores = startscores+sparescores+strikescores+doublestrikescores
endfunction
```

Here's how I would vectorize fetching all the scores together

EDIT:
Note that I'm counting a strike as a spare here so sparescores is really just summing the first throw after any frame after there was a spare or a strike
Then to balance it, strikescores is just the second throw on any frame after a strike
EDIT Again:
I had to account for two strikes in a row.  Now I think it's good

Comment: Did you test the code? Does games = 10*ones(1,21) give a score of 300?

Comment: It won't be correct unless you put dummy zeros for the second term in a strike frame.  So in this case a perfect game would be [repmat([10,0], 1, 10), 10, 10].
And oops, that is 210.
I forgot that in case of two strikes in a row, you have to take the one after which makes things a bit more tricky.  I'll fix it.  Hold on

Comment: Okay, now it gives 300.
There are 22 columns because I'm counting the last two throws in the last frame as a virtual 11th frame when the first throw is a strike.  That way there are less edge cases to deal with

Comment: I'm sorry, I see what you're asking.  As input to the function, a perfect game would be [repmat([10, 0], 1, 9), 10, 10, 10]